# move axes text in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to move axes labels in matplotlib. I thought this would work but it doesn't:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(0)
xlbl = plt.xlabel("foo")
pos = xlbl.get_position()
pos = (pos[0], pos[1] + 1)
xlbl.set_position(pos)
plt.draw()
```

However, this does work (moving in x as opposed to y):

```
xlbl = plt.xlabel("foo")
pos = xlbl.get_position()
pos = (pos[0]+1, pos[1])
xlbl.set_position(pos)
plt.draw()
```

I've searched everywhere and can only find a solution involving rcParams. This is an undesired solution because it affects all labels in my graph. I would like to move just one label.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `set_label_coords`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(0)
xlbl = plt.xlabel("foo")
pos = xlbl.get_position()
pos = (pos[0]+0.3, pos[1]+0.5)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.xaxis.set_label_coords(pos[0], pos[1])
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: the positions it takes is not the same as the ones returned by xlbl.get_position() (seems to be relative axes coordinates, I think...) but by tweaking I got it to work, thanks!